# If Statement with button background, and activity layout

Tags: android, layout, button, if-statement

How to call a buttons background, and the activity layout to match in if statement.  Can't figure out how to do this.

```
  Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  final Button quicktab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA4);
  quicktab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          Button a4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA4);
          if ( a4.getBackground() == (R.drawable.quick_btn_background));      ****ERROR****
          { 
              if (this.setContentView() = this.setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.layout_24));    ****ERROR****
              {
                  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_24);
              }
              else (this.setContentView() = this.setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.layout_63));    ****ERROR****
              {
                  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_63);
              }
          }
          else 
          {
              finish();
          }
      }
  });
```

All errors in coding or marked.  Any help would be nice. Can not seem to find anything relating to this type of if statement.

*******Update*****************
Still having errors on new code. on getBackground code, I get error: Incompatible operand types Drawable and int. on getContentView code, I get error: create method getContentView.

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

final Button quicktab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA4);
quicktab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
      Button a4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA4);
      if (a4.getBackground() == R.drawable.quick_btn_background)
      { 
          if (this.getContentView() == R.layout.layout_24)
          {
              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_24);
          }
          else if(this.getContentView() == R.layout.layout_63)
          {
              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_63);
          }
      }
      else finish();

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Please just do not append a semicolon to your `if` statements, and add some missing closing parentheses, and the syntax should be fine. Like this:

```
  Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  final Button quicktab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA4);
  quicktab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          Button a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA4);
          if (a4.getBackground() == R.drawable.quick_btn_background)
          { 
              if (this.setContentView() == this.setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.layout_24)))
              {
                  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_24);
              }
              else if(this.setContentView() == this.setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.layout_63))
              {
                  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_63);
              }
              else finish();
          }
    }
});
```

However, I am not sure at all that you have to compare `this.setContentView() == this.setContentView(...)`. Don't you mean `getContentView` somewhere? Hope this helps, good luck...

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable.quick_btn_background` is an numeric resource id (int or long - not sure) while `a4.getBackground()` returns a `Drawable`. So the comparision of those two has no sense.

Comment: Ok, then How do I get a buttons background to equal a specific background in a IF statement?

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, however you can try this: `if (a4.getBackground().equals( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quick_btn_background)))`

Comment: Usually troubles of such a kind indicate the app design should be revised.